# 3.5mm pluggable screw terminal, but male side PCB mount

Tags: pcb, connector, screw-terminal, daq

I have a few NI USB-6000 DAQs with a 3.5mm pluggable screw terminal. I want to used them in battery prototyping so I'll need to build a few unity gain differential opamps for cell voltage monitoring among other circuits.

I'd like to have my PCB attach directly to the side of the DAQ.

I've found this specimen that is for a different DAQ. I can't seem to find the right combo of words to find that connector. I doubt it's custom, there are several prototyping kits that use them.

[image: Digilent 6002-410-006 with connector highlighted]

Comment: Check wurth, degson and kaifeng

Comment: I’ve found that “eurostyle” as a keyword brings  up terminal blocks of this nature.

Comment: Be careful how you specify these connectors, the example you show has a male outer shell (mating flange), but the inner contact is female. The mfg's description refers to inner contacts.  (See the drawing on the Digikey page of the OST part.)

Comment: kaifeng?  do you mean "cixi kefa" https://www.kefaelectronic.com/KF2EDGA-3-5-3-81-Pluggable-terminal-block-pd47050564.html  according to aliexpress only available up-to 12 pins wide

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Standard pluggable terminal block 3.5 mm pitch[,](https://connectorbook.com/identification.html?m=NNK&n=two_pc_terminal_blocks_3p5&s=Std%20pluggable%20terminal%20block%203.5%20partitioned) partitioned mating face, right-angle, female PCB header:

https://www.digikey.ee/short/w2cqdqwc

[image: OSTV7201101]

{Digikey}

Comment: The NI USB-6000 DAQ you referenced only seems to have 16 I/O pins on the side. If you are sure you need the same connector type then the P/N adjusts a bit, (OSTV720xxxx to OSTV716xxxx). The PDF link on the part description page will show you the drawing. The other characters in the P/N refer to slightly different flange types/colors.  https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/filter/terminal-blocks/headers-plugs-and-sockets/370?s=N4IgjCBcoBwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDa4YcADAgLqEAOALlCAMpMBOAlgHYDmIAL6EwAJgDsCaCBSQMOAsTIgxceAGY6jFpHZc%2BgkeHXTkaLHkIlI5KiFpDjYlQB0mAAgDybACoA1CTAANgchIA

Comment: Bittersweet, my question was answered, but minimum buy is 2100 pieces. I doubt I'll get close to that. But thank you.

Comment: If you find the exact P/N needed you may be able to find some from a surplus dealer or on Ebay. Maybe even a used assembly that the connector could be scavenged from. Also, with a wide pitch connector as this there is a possibility that the parts are stackable (end to end), possibly buy multiple pieces of a lower pin count. Lastly, the USB-6000 DAQ had multiple GND connections on the connector, so you may be able to use a few lessor pinned parts and leave out one or more of the extra GND points.

Comment: You don't have to buy _that_ size. You can buy shorter ones and stack them side-by-side: https://www.digikey.ee/en/products/detail/phoenix-contact/1830472/5189126

Comment: you will need to cut (or file) back the sides to stack them,  so yeah OK for a prototype or a short run but a pain for production. if you don't like digikey prices and can wait for slower shipping https://www.aliexpress.com/item/1005003834518054.html "KF2EDGA 3.5" but you still need to cut them back to stack them

Comment: Thank all of you. Jasen, thank you for the aliexpress link. I'm only interested in 9 of the pins anyway . I love this community.